# Getting values from arrays containing stdClass PHP objects

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, stdclass

I'm obtaining information from the Facebook Graph API that returns an array that contains several stdClass Objects.  I can easily read the "top" level items such as $myGraph['id'] = 123111193 in the example below.

Can anyone show me how to get data from the stdClass Objects, for example School Name in the following example created with print_r()?

```
    Array
    (
        [id] => 123111193
        [education] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [school] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 108177302537907
                        [name] => State College Area High School
                    )

                [type] => High School
                [year] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 117615364954534
                        [name] => 1975
                    )

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [concentration] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 193334910691838
                                [name] => Individual and Family Studies
                            )

                    )

                [school] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 113618111985274
                        [name] => Pennsylvania State University
                    )
```

Comment: to get the first school name this should work: `$array['education'][0]->school->name`

Comment: already discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690971/get-data-from-php-object)

Comment: $array['education'][0]->school->name works PERFECTLY!!!

Thanks VERY much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

foreach($mainArray['education'] as $edObj) 
{
     echo $edObj->school->name;
}
```

Comment: This is not working with my FB object.  The test "is_object" is never true since the type is an array.  If I change it to "is_array" it evaluates as true yet there is no output. Any ideas would greatly help - Thanks!!!!

Comment: Sorry about that -- I had just woken up earlier when I posted this. Revised.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing fancy. If you have an std object called `$foo` and it has a `$bar` member, then you refer to it as `$foo->bar`. Example:

```
foreach ($mainArray["education"] as $value) {
    echo $value->school->name;
}
```